# vt-x/amd-v hardware acceleration is not available on your system error in a Ubuntu VM

Tags: 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my Windows 10 machine, Hardware Virtualization is enabled on it, as shown in the image here.
[settings of Ubuntu VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug9XA.png)

But if I run Vagrant in the Ubuntu VM, I get the error "
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot." [virtual box error in VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfPNp.png).

Can some one help me resolve this error.

Comment: The Hyper -V feature is already disabled on the Windows 10 machine

Comment: same here. any update/solution?

Comment: Not really. What I understand is we cannot run vagrant inside virtual box.